# ProgressBar doesnt stops

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have made an application in which user log's in his accounts.For this i have used asyncTask.Everything works fine but the thing is when i get the response i want the progress bar to stop.But it goes on continously.

Async Task

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute ();
        CommonFunctions.showProgress (c, "Please Wait", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute (s);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (s.trim ());
            JSONObject NewDataSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject ("NewDataSet");
            JSONObject Table = NewDataSet.getJSONObject ("Table");
            String User_ID = Table.getString ("User_ID");
            String Vendor_IEntity_Code = Table.getString ("Vendor_IEntity_Code");
            String Vendor_Name = Table.getString ("Vendor_Name");


            // setting the preferences
            SettingPreference.setUserId (c, User_ID);
            SettingPreference.setVendorId (c, Vendor_IEntity_Code);
            SettingPreference.setVendorName (c, Vendor_Name);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        CommonFunctions.showProgress (c, "", false);

        Crouton.makeText ((android.app.Activity) c, "Login Sucessful", Style.CONFIRM).show ();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        response = HttpRequest.post ("https://beta135.hamarisuraksha.com/web/WebService/HsJobService.asmx/IsUserValid").send ("_UserID=" + strings[0] + "&_Password=" + strings[1]).body ();
        Log.e ("Login Response", "" + response);
        return response;
    }
```

CommonFunctions

```
public class CommonFunctions {

    private Context c;


    public static void showProgress(Context context, String message, boolean isVisible) {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (context);
        progressDialog.setMessage (message);
        progressDialog.setCancelable (false);
        if (isVisible) {
            progressDialog.show ();
        } else if (isVisible == false) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing ()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (context);
```

So each time you call the `showProgress` method you are creating a new `ProgressDialog` thus it is not dismissing upon calling the method again.

**solution:**

Create only once instance of `ProgressDialog`

```
public class CommonFunctions {

    private Context c;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    public static void showProgress(Context context, String message, boolean isVisible) {

        if(progressDialog == null)
        {
             progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (context);
             progressDialog.setMessage (message);
             progressDialog.setCancelable (false);
        }

        if (isVisible) {
            progressDialog.show();
        } else if (isVisible == false) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing ()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3667909 you can accept the answer if it worked for you.  +1 from my side

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your creating instance again without progressdialog show. So on second time

```
if (progressDialog.isShowing ())
```

above condition is false.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use this approach, since these methods are provided there for a reason.
Start your Progressbar in `onPreExecute()` and simply stop it in `onPostexecute()`.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

ProgressDialog dialog;

      protected void onPreExecute() {
       dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
       dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
       dialog.setMessage("Your Message");
       dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
       dialog.setCancelable(false);
       dialog.show();
      };

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Your Code        
        return null;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       dialog.dismiss();
       // UI updates if any
      };

}.executeOnExecutor();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class CommonFunctions {

    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public static void showProgress(Context context, String message, boolean isVisible) {

        if(progressDialog == null){
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (context);
            progressDialog.setMessage (message);
            progressDialog.setCancelable (false);
        }
        if (isVisible) {
            progressDialog.show ();
        }else{
            progressDialog.dismiss ();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In showProgress() you are creating new object. So when you are calling this method to hide progress bar it is creating new object and hiding new one not the previous one.

You need to update CommonFunctions class as following.

```
public class CommonFunctions {

    private Context c;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public CommonFunctions(Context context){
      this.c = context;
      progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (context);
    }

    public static void showProgress(String message, boolean isVisible) {
            progressDialog.setMessage (message);
        progressDialog.setCancelable (false);
        if (isVisible) {
            progressDialog.show ();
        } else if (isVisible == false) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing ()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use this as following:

```
 CommonFunctions cf = new CommonFunctions(context);
```

to display progress use following:

```
cf.("Please Wait", true);
```

to hide progress use following:

```
cf.("", false);
```